# Virtualbox Host-only Adapter blocks Chrome's and Slack's internet access

Tags: networking, google-chrome, virtualbox, http-proxy, slack

I have Google Chrome version 64 (most current at the time of this writing) running on win 10 with all updates. I also have VirtualBox 5.2.6 r120293 (most current at the time of this writing), with a Host-Only network, which produces an additional network device. The device has an address (10.23.23.1) outside all other networks I am connected to (192.168.0.0).

Chrome does not connect to any sites when the Host-Only device is enabled. Disabling the device fixes the issue. Other browsers like Firefox do not have this problem. However I would like to use that network, and also would like to stick with Chrome. Also I would like to understand the problem.

How can I use the Host-Only network together with using Chrome?

**EDIT 1** It turns it seems to be proxy related. I am on a company netork with an http/https proxy. Internal sites work also with the Host-Only interface, but external sites do not. When disabling the interface, also external sites are working, without changing anything else.

**EDIT 2** Also Slack has this problem.